# var val() undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, firebug, var

```
<form>
<p>
<label>Username</label>
<input name="username" placeholder="Username" required="" type="text">
</p>
</form>    

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      var username=$("#username").val();
</script>
```

I have read a lot of posts related to this problem, but I have not found solution.

I tried with Firebug and give me this:

```
username undefined
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: there is no input with id `username`. Besides that, the input you are trying to reference doesn't seem to have a `value` attribute either.

Comment: @Sumurai8: But it will always have a non-`undefined` value. Initially that value will be `""`, but the user presumably fills something else in.

Comment: It isn't in a handler though. But I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't have an element with the `id` `"username"`. You have one with the *`name`* `"username"`. So jQuery returns an empty set when you do `$("#username")` (as there are no matching elements). When you call `val()` on an empty set, it returns `undefined`.

You can either change your field to have an `id`:

```
<input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="" type="text">
```

**Or** change your selector to use the `name`:

```
var username = $("input[name=username]").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` is selector for ID, but you don't have ID on your input.
So you could add an ID:

```
<input name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required="" type="text">
```

Loot at this : [`Id Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

try accessing element by name attribute:

```
$('input[name=username]').val()
```

or if you need to access by id, then add id attribute:

```
<input name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required="" type="text">
```